# How to "tail -f" file from a remote Unix system in Java?

Tags: java

I want to be able to get buffered input from a remote system (using SSH and username password encrytion from Java) and then "tail -f" a file, buffering the input. Is this possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Jsch to rescue: http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/

Comment: It's a BSD Licence - so, open source, free for commercial usage.  See the [licence document](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/LICENSE.txt), linked from the page above for more info.

Comment: Have you used this yourself? Is it stable in your opinion?

Comment: @Zubair Yes. I have used in critical tasks like `scp` and running remote shell script on prod environment during app deployment. I say it never failed for me.

Comment: ok, thanks. And does it support buffered streams, so that I can read the results of a "tail -f" as they come in

Comment: @Zubair I am not sure, but I hope so. There is a great example resource available here http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/ and I guess you will need something like this: http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/StreamForwarding.java I would like to know how it works.